# measure theory and convolution question

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose g, f $\in{L^2(\mathbb R)}$
Show the convolution g*f is a continuous function. 
I have been working on this problem for hours, but don't know how to approach it. should I use continuity of convolution in L1 to show it for L2? I know I have to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality somewhere but I am at a loss here. Please fill in the details since I want to learn technique also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that the translation on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is continuous.This means,that if you define the family of operators $T_{h}$ on $L^{2}$ by $T_{h}(f(x))=f(x+h)$,then $T_{h}(f)$ converges to $f$ in $L^{2}$ as $h\to 0$.To show this,use a density argument.Firstly observe that its true for compactly supported continuous functions,which form a dense subclass of $L^{2}$.Then make use the fact that if $T_{n}$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of operators on a Banach space $V$ and $U$ is a bounded operator such that $T_{n}$ converges to $U$ pointwise on a dense subspace of $V$,then $T_{n}$ converges to $U$ pointwise on $V$.Once you have proven continuity of translation in $L^2$ it's easy to prove continuity of the convolution.Indeed,if $K(x)$ denotes the convolution of $f$ and $g$,consider $|K(x+h)-K(x)|$,use Cauchy Schwarz,and finally use the continuity of translation in $L^2$ to conclude your proof.

Comment: can you help me a little more, I don't know how to proceed with the proof, i only need this part: Indeed,if K(x) denotes the convolution of f and g,consider |K(x+h)−K(x)|,use Cauchy Schwarz,and finally use the continuity of translation in L2 to conclude your proof.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz right away:
\begin{align}
    &|(f\star g)(x)-(f\star g)(y)|^2 \\ &\le \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(r)g(x-r)-f(r)g(y-r)|dr\right)^2 \\
  &\le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(r)|^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(x-r)-g(y-r)|^2dr
\end{align}
Then you can use the Fourier transform and the Plancherel theorem to write
$$
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(x-r)-g(y-r)|^2dr \\
   = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(x+r)-g(y+r)|^2dr \\
   = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{g}(s)|^2|1-e^{-is(x-y)}|^2ds
$$
Now dominated convergence gives the converges of the above to $0$ as $y\rightarrow x$.